# How can I program a bot to check to see if a user is on a specific website?

Tags: discord

I have an official Discord server for a game and I want this bot to check to see if the user is on the game's website; if they are, they are given the role 'Currently Playing'; and when they come off the site, the role is removed.

I don't know if this is possible, but this would be extremely useful for so many people.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it will be possible without asking for more information, by design. It would be a privacy issue if you could.

Theoretically you could do it by having them type their username for the game or steam or whatever into the chat like

```
/gamebot @myusername
```

Now your bot could read that and now associate the discord account with the gamer account. You would then need an API from the game that's shows who is active and the bit can now know.

Comment: Now that I reread this you should probably have them login instead like `/login` and then that gives them a URL which would take them to the site and if they login successfully it can associate the two ids.

Answer (score 1):

My interpretation of this question is that

If a player is on `OnYourWebsite.com`

It would say in their roles `playing OnYourWebsite`

This wouldn't really be possible unless you own the website **or** you are developing it. You could do this by using the `Discord API` this will let you create a discord sign in option.

Comment: Yes, use a discord OAuth.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong,

but to directly check if a User is on a Website, you need the User´s IP address.

And you can´t get a Member´s IP address on Discord.

Another way could be rich presence, I know there are Rich Presences for Websites like YouTube, but I don´t know how they work.

Here is an example:

https://github.com/PreMiD/PreMiD

You need to install a Addon and install a program.

In this case, the Server Members would have to install a Addon and download a Programm , which you would have to program.

But, I dont know more about this topic.
This is all I have got.

(I would have commented this, but I don´t have enough reputation.)